# Help with test coverage for implementation of QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have an Apex Class 'EmailPublisherLoader', which implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler, to set dynamic Email Templates, Recipients and From address in the Case Feed Email Publisher.

I am struggling with pushing the code to production, as the test class yields 74% coverage. I wonder which additional tests ca be added to raise the test code coverage.

Below is the Apex Class:

```
global class EmailPublisherLoader implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {
// Empty constructor
    global EmailPublisherLoader() { }

// The main interface method
    global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = null;

        // Check if the quick action is the standard Case Feed send email action
        for (Integer j = 0; j < defaults.size(); j++) {
            if (defaults.get(j) instanceof QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults && 
               defaults.get(j).getTargetSObject().getSObjectType() == 
                   EmailMessage.sObjectType && 
               defaults.get(j).getActionName().equals('Case.Email') && 
               defaults.get(j).getActionType().equals('Email')) {
                   sendEmailDefaults = 
                       (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(j);
                   break;
            }
        }

         if (sendEmailDefaults != null) {
            Case c = [SELECT Status, contact.Email, Additional_To__c, Additional_CC__c, Additional_BCC__c, RecordType.name FROM Case WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];
            EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject();  

    //set TO address
         String contactEmail = c.contact.Email; 
         if (c.contact.Email == c.Additional_To__c){
            emailMessage.toAddress = (c.contact.Email);
            }
            else{
                if (c.Additional_To__c != null){
                    //contactEmail is included in Additional TO
                    if (c.Additional_To__c.indexOf(contactEmail) != -1){
                        emailMessage.toAddress = (c.Additional_To__c);
                        }
                else{
                    emailMessage.toAddress = (c.contact.Email+' '+c.Additional_To__c);
                    }
                }
            }
    //set CC address
            emailMessage.ccAddress = (c.Additional_CC__c);
    //set BCC address        
            emailMessage.bccAddress = (c.Additional_BCC__c);
    //set From 'security@test.com' for 'Security' RecordType
            if (c.recordtype.name  == 'Security'){
            emailMessage.fromAddress = ('security@test.com');
            }

    //if In Reply To Id field is null we know the interface is called on page load
        if (sendEmailDefaults.getInReplyToId() == null) {

                    if (c.recordtype.name  == 'Consumer'){
                        sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(getTemplateIdHelper('Custom_Default_Consumer_Email'));                       
                        }
                        else if (c.recordtype.name  == 'Security') {
                            sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(getTemplateIdHelper('Custom_Default_Security_Email'));
                            } 
                            else {
                            sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(getTemplateIdHelper('Custom_Default_Enterprise_Email'));
                            }                

           }
          // Now, we know that the 'Reply' or 'Reply All' button has been clicked, so we load the default response template 
          else
          {
               if (c.recordtype.name  == 'Consumer'){
                            sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(getTemplateIdHelper('Custom_Default_Consumer_Email_No_Body'));
                            sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(true);
               }
               else if (c.recordtype.name  == 'Security') {
                            sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(getTemplateIdHelper('Custom_Default_Security_Email'));
                            sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(true);
               }
                   else {
                            sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(getTemplateIdHelper('Custom_Default_Enterprise_Email_No_Body'));
                            sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(true);
                   }      
          }
         }
       }

    private Id getTemplateIdHelper(String templateApiName) {
        Id templateId = null;
        try {
            templateId = [select id, name from EmailTemplate 
                          where developername = : templateApiName].id;   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('Unble to locate EmailTemplate using name: ' + 
                templateApiName + ' refer to Setup | Communications Templates ' 
                    + templateApiName);
        }
        return templateId;
    }
}
```

And the Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class EmailPublisherLoaderTest {
    static Case myCase {get;set;}
    static EmailMessage myMsg {get;set;}

    static testmethod void EmailPublisherLoader_NoReplyToId() {
        Exception failureDuringExecution = null;
        init();
        init2();
        init3();
        init4();

        //create QuickActionDefaults
        List<Map<String, Object>> defaultSettingAsObject = new List<Map<String, Object>>
        {
          new Map<String, Object>
          {
                'targetSObject' => new EmailMessage(),
                'contextId' => myCase.Id,
                'actionType' => 'Email',
                'actionName' => 'Case.Email',
                'fromAddressList' => new List<String> { 'salesforce@test.com' }
          }
        };

        List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults> defaultsSettings = 
            (List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(defaultSettingAsObject), List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults>.class);
        Test.startTest();
        try {
            (new EmailPublisherLoader()).onInitDefaults(defaultsSettings);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            failureDuringExecution = e; 
        }

        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(null, failureDuringExecution, 'There was an exception thrown during the test!');
    }
    static testmethod void EmailPublisherLoader_WithReplyToId() {
        Exception failureDuringExecution = null;
        init();
        init2();
        init3();
        init4();

        //create QuickActionDefaults
        List<Map<String, Object>> defaultSettingAsObject = new List<Map<String, Object>>
        {
          new Map<String, Object>
          {
                'targetSObject' => new EmailMessage(),
                'replyToId' => myMsg.Id,
                'contextId' => myCase.Id,
                'actionType' => 'Email',
                'actionName' => 'Case.Email',
                'fromAddressList' => new List<String> { 'salesforce@test.com' }
          }
        };

        List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults> defaultsSettings = 
            (List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(defaultSettingAsObject), List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults>.class);
        Test.startTest();
        try {
            (new EmailPublisherLoader()).onInitDefaults(defaultsSettings);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            failureDuringExecution = e; 
        }

        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(null, failureDuringExecution, 'There was an exception thrown during the test!');
    }

    static void init(){
        myCase = 
            new Case(
                Status='Status'
                , Origin='Email'
                , Reason = 'Reason'
                , RecordTypeId = '01261000000XfOl'
            );
        insert myCase;

        myMsg = 
            new EmailMessage(
                ParentId = myCase.Id
            );
        insert myMsg;
    }
     static void init2(){
        myCase = 
            new Case(
                Status='Status'
                , Origin='Email'
                , Reason = 'Reason'
                , RecordTypeId = '01261000000XfOq'
            );
        insert myCase;

        myMsg = 
            new EmailMessage(
                ParentId = myCase.Id
            );
        insert myMsg;
    }
    static void init3(){
        myCase = 
            new Case(
                Status='Status'
                , Origin='Email'
                , Reason = 'Reason'
                , RecordTypeId = '01261000000iuJL'
            );
        insert myCase;

        myMsg = 
            new EmailMessage(
                ParentId = myCase.Id
            );
        insert myMsg;
    }
    static void init4(){
        myCase = 
            new Case(
                Status='Status'
                , Origin='Email'
                , Reason = 'Reason'
                , RecordTypeId = '01261000000XfP0'
            );
        insert myCase;

        myMsg = 
            new EmailMessage(
                ParentId = myCase.Id
            );
        insert myMsg;
    }
    @isTest
static void test_mockIfAtAllPossible(){
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to raise the code coverage by adding the 'contact' to my tests.